# "dotenv.load() is not a function" while trying to run a Node script

Tags: node.js

I am trying to replicate the import script to get my Firebase RTD data to Algolia. When trying to run the script, it fails and says dotenv.load is not a function.

I have the .env file in the same directory as the index.js file. I have tried moving the .env file around but that doesn't help. Here is the beginning code for the index.js:

```
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const firebase = require('firebase');

//load values from the ./env file in this direcotry into process.env
dotenv.load();

//config firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
});
```

What can I do? Using .config() on the requirement does not help either.

Comment: Can you run `tree` in the root of your project directory so that we can see what your project tree looks like?

Comment: There is [this](https://github.com/keithmorris/node-dotenv-extended#usage) which does use `.load` but based on your `require` it doesn't look like that's what you're using.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Based on [NPM documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) you should use dotenv.config().

Comment: Dang. Looks like the tutorial I'm basing this off of is pretty outdated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'my-app/.env'});
```

I right-clicked on the .env file to get the relative path.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, when you post an answer with code, place a code format. You can find it in the tool bar of the post editor.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it depends on the path of .env file and also, the way you are executing the script. Maybe the firebase commands to run (e.g., `firebase serve --only functions`) is different of to run `node index.js` in the path perspective (if you are using a cloud function).

In other words, you need to determine path of your main script and, then, determine the relative path of your `.env` file to this and set this path to `dotenv.config()`.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @ahmad's answer, the [documentation](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) for the package asks to have you use `dotenv.config()` to load your .env file. Additionally depending on where you have the path, you'd pass the object `{ path: /path/to/your/file }`. It would possibly help if you required the `path` package from the nodejs standard library to resolve paths to ensure you're getting the correct path to the file.