# Type Error: require(..).load is not a function?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

Type Error: require(..).load is not a function

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
     require('dotenv').load() 
}
```

Comment: do you mean `require('dotenv').config()` ?

Comment: Already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271926/dotenv-load-is-not-a-function-while-trying-to-run-a-node-script

Comment: Looks like require(..).load() is pretty outdated. Thanks.